# How can I spawn an entire preconfigured room using Command Blocks/Armor Stands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a room/dungeon, then use command blocks to spawn that room at a certain location, using Armor Stands.

I know I can use the `/clone` command but how would I specify what rotations so it doesn't get placed in the other rooms? How do I even spawn the Armor Stands at the locations that the rooms can spawn in?

Comment: I think the clone command would work great. You would just need to learn how it works. What cords in the command copies the build and what pastes it. You can experiment with the command and see how it works. You can then try to place your build at the armor stand and see what the outcome is. You can then figure out what to change. Here is a good video explaining how the command works: https://youtu.be/eSs7m_a31BM?si=NgoAb6cw8Y4kiWMQ

Answer (score -3):

Here is the answer:
Use Structure blocks.
At the time where you load it you can set the rotation! Watch this YouTube video I found for you:

Watch full if you don't know what this is, watch from `5:00` for rotation Tutorial!

Comment: Btw.

Where can I down load your map?
And how long do I need to wait for the Upload?
Do you need more  help? (Build/commands)